# Blue highlight when hovering in drop down menu

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to change the blue highlight color when hovering in a drop down menu? I'm using the drop-down list on my page. I have a drop down menu that allows you to choose the topic.

I would greatly appreciate any help or feedback on this topic.

[image]

Comment: Questions seeking help ("**why isn't, or how to make, this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a _specific problem or error and the **shortest code necessary**_ to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: No, you can't change that on the built-in dropdown element.

Answer (score 0):

That blue colour is called an [outline](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/outline), and is used for accessibility reasons.
For example, when you press the tab key to move between form elements, an outline is commonly used so the user knows what element is currently selected.

You can remove this outline with the following CSS:

```
select:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

However, It is not recommended to remove this. If you must, you should provide an alternative style by using a background colour, changing the text colour, or provide a custom outline instead of the browser default.
ex:

```
select:focus {
    outline: 2px solid red;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.dropdown-item.active, .dropdown-item:active {
    background-color: red;
}
```

These are the Bootstrap classes that need to be overwritten if you wish to change the highlighted background colour when you hover over the dropdown item (i.e. when it is "active").

The classes can be discovered by opening up the Elements section within Google Dev Tools (F12) and then highlighting the element that you wish to restyle. Finding the active states of classes can be a little more tricky and may require a little more digging into the HTML.

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer by editing it, such that others can learn from it